# Edit a file on CentOS 6.3 Minimal

Tags: linux, command-line, centos

I installed CentOS 6.3 Minimal on VMWare Player, and I realized how 'minimal' the setup is...

Don't have network connectivity. From what I searched on google, I need to edit the file

> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

but since I don't have any editor installed (as far as I know), I don't know how to edit the file.

How do I edit the file????

Comment: `vi` should be installed. Since `vi` is the POSIX standard editor, it is unlikely that you will find yourself on a Unix or Linux machine without it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From CentOS 6.3 [release notes for the minimal install](http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOSMinimalCD6.3), `vi` is available.

Answer (score 4):

Type

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

Press <kbd>i</kbd> to insert. Once finished with your changes, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> then `:wq` to save changes.